# How do Swift Playgrounds Work?

Tags: swift-playground

I have experience working with Swift 3 to create iOS apps, however I am trying to create a playground (for the WWDC scholarship) and I have no idea how they work.

I downloaded the following sample code from online, and added it to my iOS playground:

```
import UIKit  
import PlaygroundSupport  

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))  
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue 

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

However when I press the run button, it says that it is running but nothing happens.

Am I supposed to have an iOS simulator open? Am I supposed to be running a certain app that will show the output?

Answer (score 0):

Did you got your answer if not then use (show assistant editor button )[image]

And then on the left side it would open and you can see the view